# Conditionally render attribute

Tags: jsf

In JSF, how can I conditionally render an onclick attribute in Facelets.

```
<div onclick="$(this).applyFancybox({trigger: !$.browser.msie, target: (event.srcElement || event.target)}); return false;">
```

How to get something like:

```
<div #{xBean.method eq null ? 'onclick="$(this).applyFancybox({trigger: !$.browser.msie, target: (event.srcElement || event.target)}); return false;' : ''>
```

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery

```
if (condition)
{
    $("#myDiv").click(functionA);
}
else
{
    $("#myDiv").click(functionB);
}
```

Comment: How can i add an onclick event on an div with this html structure?
<span id="x">
   <div>
      ....

<script>
  $("#proposal-status div").click(...)
</script>
It throws an error saying that the guid can not be find

Comment: You never mentioned a guid. That wouldn't apply to this scenario  unless it was part of the id or condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as this:

```
<div onclick="#{true ? 'console.log(true)' : ''}">Your contents.</div>
```

will render:

```
<div onclick="console.log(true)">Your contents.</div>
```

whereas:

```
<div onclick="#{false ? 'console.log(true)' : ''}">Your contents.</div>
```

will render:

```
<div>Your contents.</div>
```

Obviously, you'd need to change `true|false` with an actual condition etc. So your example would become:

```
<div onclick="#{xBean.method eq null ? '$(this).applyFancybox({trigger: !$.browser.msie, target: (event.srcElement || event.target)}); return false;' : ''}">
```